# Excel Search for Matching Value and Highlight Differences in That Row

Tags: microsoft-excel

We have two sheets, Sheet1:

[image]

and Sheet2:

[image]

Both sheets have approximately the same amount of data, but there are differences. I want to match IDs between Sheet1 and Sheet2 and highlight any differences on Sheet1 found in the corresponding row, like so:

[image]

My attempt at the conditional formatting logic is as follows: Do a lookup on A2 of Sheet1 in the A column of Sheet2 and if there is a match, compare Sheet1's B2-E2 to the B-E match of Sheet2. Move to the A3 of Sheet1 and repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula to use in the Conditional Formatting is:

```
=NOT(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A1:E1000,2)=B2)
```

This is for column B, and just change the `B2` at the end to `C2` etc. for the other columns, and for each column increase the `2`(after the `A1:E1000`) with one number.

Here are screenshots of how if should be. tested and works for me:
[image]

And here is the furmula for coulmn B and C:
[image]

[image]

Comment: This method seems to be on the right track, but it highlighted the wrong fields

Comment: Can you explain? Which fields did you want it to highlight and which fields did it highlight?

Comment: [Here is a link with pictures of what happened](http://imgur.com/a/1KRwQ)

Comment: Oh....that happens when you're not following exactly....  You applied it to the whole columns so it is everything with one cell up, you should've done the "applies to" just from row 2. Like "=$B$2:$B$1000" instead of "=$B:$B"

Comment: [I updated it](https://imgur.com/o8Pp7bR), but with no luck

Comment: I am not sure what's wrong with your sheet, works for me like a charm. Would you mind uploading the Excel file to somewhere?

Comment: File can be found here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B142DWqQLhl3NkU5ZEtfb2ltT3c

Comment: I see the problem, instead of doing the formula "=NOT(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A1:E1000,2)=B2)" as I did it, you were with one cell down, like this "=NOT(VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!A2:E1001,2)=B3)". Here is the file back uploaded, fixed how it should've been https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ha_cjJs64USXZtWW1QQXhxV00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @dzampino, glad to help. If my answer was correct please accept the answer as the correct answer.